# Refactor Java Web App using JBoss Seam to use Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, seam

I need to convert a project written with JBoss Seam framework to use spring framework. I need to remove JBoss Seam completely. In my classes there are annotations like

- @Name
- @Scope
- @DataModel
- @DataModelSelection
- @In
- @Out
- @Begin
- @Factory
- @Create
- @End
- @Destroy
- @Remove

What are the equivalent Spring annotations for above JBoss Seam annotations? If there are not any equivalents, how do I handle those annotations in Spring?

There is also a following variable in the code.

```
@In
private FacesMessages facesMessages;
```

Here FacesMessages is a JBoss Seam framework class. What will be the replacement for this class in Spring framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those annotation you have mentioned, as long as you understand both SEAM and Spring, it will not be an issue.  Since you were asking about it you are probably lacking both knowledge.  Most of the life cycle and those annotations are pretty straigntforward once you get to know Springs. 
FacesMessages mostly used so you can show messages to the front end or UI, so you can replace that with any View technology(freemarker, jsp, etc).  But you would have to pretty much rewrite everything and rewire everything.  Most likely JBoss SEAM application you are referring to is using JBoss 5, and Java 7 at the most and likely old hibernate if any with EJBs.  You need to worry more about pages.xml and components.xml or any rules that are in place.